# Constructor Chaining in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, constructor, constructor-chaining

I am trying to chain these constructors:

```
public class Method1
{
    public Method1(string a, string b) : this(a, b, "", "")
    {

    }

    public Method1(string c, string d) : this("", "", c, d)
    {

    }

    public Method1(string a, string b, string c, string d)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?
Currently it's showing a compile time error.

Comment: It would help if you included the text of the error. But I'm guessing it's nothing to do with *chaining*, per se, and more that you have two constructors with identical signatures. How is `new Method1("x","y");` meant to be resolved to your first or second constructor?

Comment: Constructor signatures are differentiated based on the position and type of the parameter. You have 2 constructors with the same types in the same positions, the compiler cant compile that because it is not resolvable at run time (which constructor would be called when 2 strings are passed in?).

Answer (score 5):

You're using C# 4, so why not use optional parameters?

```
 public Method1(string a = "", string b = "", string c = "", string d = "")
```

You can call your desired behaviour as:

```
Method1(c: "some value", d: "some other value");

Method1(a: "some other other value", b:"another other value");
```

...or any combination of the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The common approach to this kind of thing is to have a private constructor that has all the parameters you need, and then to write a set of well-named public static methods that call the private constructor with the appropriate parameters.

This is a nice approach because you can give sensible names to your static creator methods, whereas with constructors you can't (of course).

For example:

```
public class Method1
{
    public static Method1 Method1FromAB(string a, string b)
    {
        return new Method1(a, b, "", "");
    }

    public static Method1 Method1FromCD(string c, string d)
    {
        return new Method1("", "", c, d);
    }

    private Method1(string a, string b, string c, string d)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is generally only a good idea with sealed classes though. The OP may decide that the class in question should be sealed, but if not, this has the problem that it cannot be used in base constructor invocations.

Comment: @hvd True although if it's not sealed you could have a protected constructor to call from the derived classes.

Comment: If it is not sealed it would not scale well due to a lack of being able to have the static methods as abstract.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Method1(string a, string b) : this(a, b, "", "")
```

and

```
public Method1(string c, string d) : this("", "", c, d)
```

have the same method signature

you can perform this but not with the same method signature for your constructors

Answer (score 1):

```
public Method1(string a, string b) : this(a, b, "", "")
{

}

public static Method1 CreateMethodWithEndParams(string c, string d)
{
    Method1 method = new Method1("", "", c, d);

    return method;
}

public Method1(string a, string b, string c, string d)
{

}
```

You can have something like this. When you want to create the object with c,d

```
 Method1 method = Method1.CreateMethodWithEndParams("c", "d");
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending of what kind the variables a, b, c and d represent, and how you use them, you could make structs for them.
Then you can create overloads for the constructors, that would make it easier to comprehend.

```
using System;

namespace ConstructorChaining
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var chainerAB = new ConstructorChainer(new A("aa"), new B("bb"));
            Console.WriteLine($"chainerAB - A:{chainerAB.A.Value}, B:{chainerAB.B.Value}, C:{chainerAB.C.Value}, D:{chainerAB.D.Value}");
    
            var chainerCD = new ConstructorChainer(new C("cc"), new D("dd"));
            Console.WriteLine($"chainerCD - A:{chainerCD.A.Value}, B:{chainerCD.B.Value}, C:{chainerCD.C.Value}, D:{chainerCD.D.Value}");
        }
    }


    public class ConstructorChainer
    {
        public A A { get; set; }
        public B B { get; set; }
        public C C { get; set; }
        public D D { get; set; }


        public ConstructorChainer(A a, B b) : this(a, b, new C(""), new D("")){}
    
        public ConstructorChainer(C c, D d) : this(new A(""),  new B(""), c, d){}

        private ConstructorChainer(A a, B b, C c, D d)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
            C = c;
            D = d;
        }
    }

    public struct A
    {
        public A(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public string Value{ get; set;}
    }

    public struct B
    {
        public B(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public string Value{ get; set;}
    }

    public struct C
    {
        public C(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public string Value{ get; set;}
    }

    public struct D
    {
        public D(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public string Value{ get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a massive amount of overhead for circumventing what is likely a basic design flaw

Comment: Indeed a lot of code with the structs. It would be nice to make easier types. 
Seems that there is not a real ideal solution for this that is quite error proof. 
Perhaps the initial structure of the question should be revised.